# Real time slam tracking on windows with monocular camera

Tags: windows, webcam, real-time, tracking

I am looking for slam tracking open source lib/software - Any fast, tiny and simple open source SLAM implementation for camera pose estimation and viewMatrix?

I am looking for an Open source SLAM implementation - Basically I am looking for a fast and easy implementation which could give me camera pose, frame and viewMatrix of the camera == similar to ARKit or ARCore - Where I can get the camera viewMatrix.

I have looked into various implementation like -

ORGSLAM2 - https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2 - Lots of bundled library and dont want to dive in the code

Or LSD_SLAM - https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam

Basic requirement - Some kind of fast SLAM implementation like ARKit but for Windows. To get started here - I need the image, pose estimation and viewMatrix information.

A real time monocular slam /tracking implementation

Any help or pointer would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I found a [list of SLAM libraries on Github](https://github.com/tzutalin/awesome-visual-slam) that may be useful. It includes several monocular SLAM and RGBD SLAM libraries.